# GUI with Python using Tkinter, errors

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI with 2 buttons. But I keep running into the same error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as t

def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print("ID:", ind[0]+4, ", Name:",method[ind[0]+2], ", Value-x:",x[ind[0]+2])

def plotpareto():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax1.scatter(x[2:], y[2:], picker=True)
    for i in index:
        ax1.scatter(x[i], y[i], c = "r")
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
    plt.show()

def compute():
    first = input("Enter Highest Priority: ")
    second = input("Enter Next Highest Priority: ")
    imp = input("Enter Implementation: ")
    if first == 'GC':
        if imp == 'P02':
            col1 = 'P02.1'
        if imp == 'P01':
            col1 == 'P01.1'
        if imp == 'Wille':
            col1 = 'Wille.1'
        if imp == 'ISM':
            col1 = 'ISM.1'
    if second == 'GC':
        if imp == 'P02':
            col2 = 'P02.1'
        if imp == 'P01':
            col2 == 'P01.1'
        if imp == 'Wille':
            col2 = 'Wille.1'
        if imp == 'ISM':
            col2 = 'ISM.1'
    if first == 'QC':
        if imp == 'P02':
            col1 = 'P02.2'
        if imp == 'P01':
            col1 == 'P01.2'
        if imp == 'Wille':
            col1 = 'Wille.2'
        if imp == 'ISM':
            col1 = 'ISM.2'
    if second == 'QC':
        if imp == 'P02':
            col2 = 'P02.2'
        if imp == 'P01':
            col2 == 'P01.2'
        if imp == 'Wille':
            col2 = 'Wille.2'
        if imp == 'ISM':
            col2 = 'ISM.2'

    xl = pd.read_excel("Treecover1.xlsx", na_values = '1000')
    global x
    global y

    x = list(xl[col1])
    y = list(xl[col2])
    global method
    method = list(xl['Methods'])

    minx = 9999
    temp = []

    i = 2
    while i < len(x):
        if int(x[i]) < minx and int(x[i]) != 0:
            temp.clear()
            temp.append(i)
            minx = x[i]
        elif int(x[i]) == minx:
            temp.append(i)
        i+=1

    miny = y[temp[0]]

    index = []
    for j in temp:
        if y[j] < miny and y[j] != 0:
            miny = y[j]
            index.clear()
            index.append(j)
        elif y[j] == miny:
            index.append(j)

"""window = t.Tk()
btn = t.Button(window, text = 'Compute')
btn1 = t.Button(window, text = 'Plot')
btn.pack()
btn1.pack()`enter code here`
window.mainloop()"""
```

Error:
2017-02-25 22:05:41.256 Python[85189:5428235] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1053ca2a0
2017-02-25 22:05:41.257 Python[85189:5428235] An uncaught exception was raised
2017-02-25 22:05:41.257 Python[85189:5428235] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1053ca2a0

Please help.

Comment: >>> from appJar import gui
>>> app = gui()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appJar/appjar.py", line 410, in __init__
    self.exe_file = os.path.basename(theMain.__file__)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me; however, the buttons aren't linked to this code's functions so they do nothing when pressed. Regardless, the following GUI displays with no errors:

[image]

My first thought when python code works on one machine and not another is that an unexpected version of python is running when I execute the program (i.e. 2.X instead of 3.X in this case) or one of my external modules (i.e. pandas, matplotlib, or tkinter) is corrupt or otherwise acting screwy on the suspect machine.

It would be useful to know the following:

1. Is this current code (exactly as is) throwing an error for you?
2. If so, is this the full error output? Normally, python traces an error back to a particular line, which would obviously be very helpful.
3. If possible, could you see if this issue can be replicated using dummy data instead of the spreadsheet? It will be difficult for anyone but you to test this code properly without having the spreadsheet you are using. Just a thought.

Comment: Do you know how to reinstall python on Mac?

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy myself so I am hesitant to provide any advice here. [This](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/) article may be useful. I do feel inclined to say that a reinstall of python seems like it may be overkill in this situation, but I can't claim to know what's causing the error at this point either. A quick web-search revealed a few commonalities among people experiencing this error: Mac, Matplotlib, and Tkinter. Seems more like a module issue at this point to me.

Comment: >>> from appJar import gui
>>> app = gui()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appJar/appjar.py", line 410, in __init__
    self.exe_file = os.path.basename(theMain.__file__)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'



This gives an error by itself

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to at this point. Please open up a new question.